# tkinter: change foreground color of specific menu items

Tags: python, user-interface, menu, colors, tkinter

With TKinter, is it possible to change the text color of only certain items in a menu?  I want to make less popular items have less contrast so users can quickly find the most frequently used items.  So far, I've only found `Menu`'s `foreground` option, which changes the color of everything (not particular items), or making the specific items' `state` option `disabled` to change the color, but they should still be able to be clicked to do something.  Any tips? I'm hoping there's a way I could do this using the `Menu` or `Menubutton` classes without having to re-implement a menu from scratch for this one feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`entryconfig`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.entryconfig-method) method, which works by passing the index of the menu command, then an option from the list of [add method options](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.add-method). Here's an example:

```
root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open")
filemenu.add_command(label="Save")
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

#entryconfig method to change the item with index '0' to white
filemenu.entryconfig(0, foreground='white')

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks - this works!  I'd tried it earlier and got an error when trying to use `foreground` as an entry option, so I'd incorrectly assumed it must be only an option for the entire `Menu`... but I'd since changed my environment a bit and now this works perfectly! (: